# Is there a way to make Crystal Reports to get paginated data from a datasource?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

We're testing the `SAP Crystal Reports` for ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2010 to see whether or not it meets our needs.

One flaw we have detected that makes it unfeasable to use is that, for some reason, when connected to our IDataSource that returns a collection of objects, the `CrystalReportViewer` does not ask for paginated data. It gets the `DataSourceView` and calls its `ExecuteSelectMethod` passing an `DataSourceSelectArguments` that does not ask for paginated data. It just brings everything from the datasource. The `CanPage` property of the `DataSourceView` returns true. It doesn't even ask for count.

On the other hand, the pagination on top of the control shows an uncertain number of pages, what makes us believe that there might be a way to work with paginated data.

The fact that it retrieves everything may cause the preview of a 100+ pages report to take forever.

Is there a way to make it to work with paginated data? Or a faster way to present to the user a preview of very long reports?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are querying/retrieving the data, it can have a big impact on how it's pulled.

If you use a stored procedure in SQL Server, you will get really fast results, because everything takes place on the DB server. In many cases though, if you have random datasources joined together, Crystal has no choice but to pull ALL the data to the client machine and "massage" it into a temp database it can process.

Also, make sure you don't use Page N of M on your pages. That also forces Crystal do to more work than necessary to show you page 1. Page N of M forces it to determine total page count before it shows you the first page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But SAP answered by question at SAP forum saying the data-source will always pull all the data

Comment: I didn't say it would NOT pull all the data. It will. I was telling you what to look at to make it faster or appear faster to you and/or the end user.